# Java function continues after return statement

Tags: java, search, recursion, binary-search-tree, closest

I have this assignment for a BST where I have to find the closest node to a given one. Obviously if the node is in the tree, it will get returned. Otherwise, the node that needs to be returned is the one that is closest on the tree (it can be on either side).

The script works fine, except in the situation where the node is present. Instead of returning the node, the function keeps going and spits out a different node instead of killing the function. I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

The tree is structured as so:

- It is composed of nodes
- Each node has an "entry" (a string value), a "right" and a "left"

Here's what I've got, thanks!

```
    public Entry getClosestEntry(String w) { 
            if (root == null) return null;
            else if (root.left == null && root.right == null) return root.entry;
            else return getClosestEntry(w, root, null, null, null); 
    }
    private Entry getClosestEntry(String w, Node baseNode, Node highestLow, Node lowestHi, Node finalClosest) {
        System.out.println("Dict: " + this);
        System.out.println("Top string to compare: " + w);
        System.out.println("Top baseNode: " + baseNode.entry.word);
        if (w.compareTo(baseNode.entry.word) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Top finalClosest is baseNode: " + baseNode.entry.word);
            finalClosest = baseNode;
        } else {
            if (highestLow != null) System.out.println("Top highestLow: " + highestLow.entry.word);
            else System.out.println("Top highestLow is null");
            if (lowestHi != null) System.out.println("Top lowestHi: " + lowestHi.entry.word);
            else System.out.println("Top lowestHi is null");
            if (finalClosest != null) System.out.println("Top finalClosest: " + finalClosest.entry.word);
            else System.out.println("Top finalClosest is null");

            int cmp = w.compareTo(baseNode.entry.word);

            if (cmp < 0) {
                System.out.println("Word is less than base.");
                if (lowestHi == null) {
                    lowestHi = baseNode;
                    System.out.println("lowestHi set to: " + lowestHi.entry.word);
                }
                else {
                    if (w.compareTo(lowestHi.entry.word) < 0 && baseNode.entry.word.compareTo(lowestHi.entry.word) < 0) {
                        lowestHi = baseNode;
                        System.out.println("lowestHi changed to: " + lowestHi.entry.word);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Returning right side of base.");
                if (baseNode.right != null) getClosestEntry(w, baseNode.right, highestLow, lowestHi, finalClosest);
            } else { 
                System.out.println("Word is greater than base.");
                if (highestLow == null) {
                    highestLow = baseNode;
                    System.out.println("highestLow set to: " + highestLow.entry.word);
                }
                else {
                    if (w.compareTo(highestLow.entry.word) > 0 && baseNode.entry.word.compareTo(highestLow.entry.word) > 0) {
                        highestLow = baseNode;
                        System.out.println("highestLow changed to: " + highestLow.entry.word);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Returning left side of base.");
                if (baseNode.left != null) getClosestEntry(w, baseNode.left, highestLow, lowestHi, finalClosest);
            }

            if (lowestHi == null && highestLow != null && finalClosest == null) {
                System.out.println("lowestHi is null, so finalClosest must be highestLow.");
                finalClosest = highestLow;
            } else if (highestLow == null && lowestHi != null && finalClosest == null) {
                System.out.println("highestLow is null, so finalClosest must be lowestHi.");
                finalClosest = lowestHi;
            } else if (lowestHi == null && highestLow == null && finalClosest == null) {
                System.out.println("Both sides are null, so node must be null.");
                return null;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Both sides are there. Default to highestLow if finalClosest is null");
                if (finalClosest == null) finalClosest = highestLow;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final Closest: " + finalClosest.entry.word);
        return finalClosest.entry;
    }
```

Comment: `if (...) return getClosestEntry(...);`, not `if (...) getClosestEntry(...);`

Comment: @Dukeling I've been down that road...does the exact same thing.

Comment: @ClaytonAndrewCohn In that case the line can be removed since the result is not used anywhere. eg `if (baseNode.left != null) getClosestEntry(w, baseNode.left, highestLow, lowestHi, finalClosest);` will just be dead code since the result is `return finalClosest.entry;` and the recursive call does not mutate any values.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] (a complete program along with example input and output)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was forgetting to address certain scenarios before.